# Boolean values are not parsed properly in Type Script Angular

Tags: angular, http, typescript, boolean, rxjs

have two model class in angular one is Fein and another one is StateAccountDetails

```
export class Fein{
id:number
FeinName:string;
ActiveStatus:boolean;
StateAccountDetails:Array<StateAccountDetails>   
constructor()   {
StateAccountDetails = new Array<StateAccountDetails>();   } }

export class StateAccountDetails 
{
  id:number;
  AccountName:string;
  AcountStatus:boolean;
  LegalStatus:boolean;}
```

I have called a webApi .

```
this.http.get('http://...').map(res => <Array<Fein>>res.json())  .subscribe(data => { // data corresponds to a list of Fein  });
```

The weApi returns List< Fein > objects. The objects are parsing succesfully.

But the issue is while parsing data some of the boolean objects are parsed as string like "True" or "False".

The object looks like

```
StateAccountDetails {  id= 1;AccountName ="MyAccount";AcountStatus "True"; LegalStatus = true;}
```

In the above stateaccountdetails object the LegalStatus value is parsed as boolean true or false

but the AcountStatus value is parsed as string "True" or "False"....
because of this parsing. the Filter method fails as 
filter(x=> x. AccountStatus == true) or filter(x=>x. AccountStatus == False)

Comment: Are you sure that your API returns boolean not strings? Can you post whole response?

Comment: If you're getting `"True"` where you should get `true` that's likely a problem in the *server*, not Angular/TS. But if you can't fix it at the other end you can easily write a function to deserialise the response data correctly and `.map` it onto the observable of JSON.

Comment: @AntonLee yes. Sure.. My webapi returns boolean value

Comment: @jonrsharpe one property is getting as true another property is getting as "True".. But both are returning as boolean from WebApi

Comment: @jonrsharpe . Could you please give one example

Comment: Please give a [mcve], then. Make an effort to implement it and show the results if you can't make it work.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check that

Comment: the above code is the example

Comment: please provide server response

Comment: Your example shows zero attempt to parse the response, so it's no surprise it doesn't work.

Comment: {

"id":12,
"FeinName":"Feinname1",
"ActiveStatus":true,
"StateAccountDetails":
[
{
"id":56,
"AccountName":"AccountName1",
"AcountStatus":true,
"LegalStatus":false
},
{
"id":59,
"AccountName":"AccountName2",
"AcountStatus":true,
"LegalStatus":true
}
]  
}

Comment: @jonrsharpe . I have assisgned that data to another local variable. But i didn't mention here

Comment: I have got that data in my local variable. There is no issue in that. but the issue is with one boolean variable

Comment: Have you tried double notting result so x = !!(x)

Comment: Fundamentally though assigning to another local variable isn't the same as parsing. *Try parsing it.*

Comment: @jonrsharpe how

Answer (score 0):

```js
export class Fein {
  id: number
  FeinName: string;
  ActiveStatus: boolean;
  StateAccountDetails: StateAccountDetails[];
    constructor() {
     // StateAccountDetails = new Array < StateAccountDetails > ();
    }
}

export class StateAccountDetails {
  id: number;
  AccountName: string;
  AcountStatus: boolean;
  LegalStatus: boolean;
}
```

```js
this.http.get('http://...')
  .map(res => res.json() as Fein[])
  .subscribe((data: Fein[]) => {
    // data corresponds to a list of Fein
  });
```

Try this if it fixes the issue